# Porque no puedo imprimir los datos extraídos de la API?

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy usando Fetch Api para encontrar nombres con orígenes de distintos países e imprimirlos.

```js
document.querySelector('#generar-nombre').addEventListener('submit', cargarNombres);

El resultado es el siguiente:
[![Es el resultado de la busqueda][1]][1]

function cargarNombres(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Leer las variables
    const origen = document.getElementById('origen');
    const origenSeleccionado = origen.options[origen.selectedIndex].value;

    const genero = document.getElementById('genero');
    const generoSeleccionado = genero.options[genero.selectedIndex].value;

    const cantidad = document.getElementById('numero').value;


    let url = '';
    url += 'https://randomuser.me/api/?';
    // Si hay origen agregarlo a la URL
    if(origenSeleccionado !== '') {
        url += `nat=${origenSeleccionado}&`;
    }
    // Si hay un genero agregarlo a la URL
    if(origenSeleccionado !== '') {
        url += `gender=${generoSeleccionado}&`;
    }
    // Si hay una cantidad agregarlo a la URL
    if(cantidad !== '') {
        url += `results=${cantidad}`;
    }

    // Crear fetch
    fetch(url)
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            let html = `<h2>Nombres Generados</h2>`;
            html += `<ul class="lista">`;
            data.results.forEach(function(nombre) {
                html += `
                    <li>nombre.name.first</li>
                `;
            });
            html += `</ul>`;
            document.querySelector('#resultado').innerHTML = html;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="contenido" class="contenido">
            <h1>Generador de Nombres</h1>
            <form action="#" id="generar-nombre">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="six columns">
                        <label for="origen">Origen del Nombre:</label>
                        <select class="u-full-width" id="origen">
                            <option value=''>-- Seleccione --</option>
                            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                            <option value="BR">Brasil</option>
                            <option value="CA">Canadaa</option>
                            <option value="ES">España</option>
                            <option value="FR">Francia</option>
                            <option value="IR">Irlanda</option>
                            <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="GB">Gran Bretaña</option>
                            <option value="US">America</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="genero">Genero:</label>
                        <select class="u-full-width" id="genero">
                                <option value=''>-- Seleccione --</option>
                                <option value="male">Hombre</option>
                                <option value="female">Mujer</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Nombres a Generar</label>
                        <input type="number" id="numero" class="u-full-width" min="1" max="15" value="5">
                        <input class="button-primary u-full-width" type="submit" value="Generar">
                    </div>

                    <div class="six columns">
                        <div id="resultado"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Agrego imagen del resultado obtenido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no puedes imprimir? ¿Recibes datos, mensaje o error? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega esa información.

Comment: Verificaste que te lleguen los resultados desde la api, mirando la pestaña red? La url es correcta?

Comment: Intenta hacer un *console.log(data)* para ver que te retornan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe a un detalle sencillo, estas usando template literals sin usar su mayor virtud, que es renderizar variables, checa aquello que tienes:

```
data.results.forEach(function(nombre) {
    html += `
        <li>nombre.name.first</li>
    `;
});
```

En especial esta parte de aqui:

```
<li>nombre.name.first</li>
```

Lo que deberias tener enrealidad es esto:

```
data.results.forEach(function(nombre) {
    html += `
        <li>${nombre.name.first}</li>
    `;
});
```

Es decir, esto:

```
<li>${nombre.name.first}</li>
```

Es decir, lo unico que se te olvidaba era usar `${}` donde dentro de `${aqui}` será renderizada tu variable.